# Query string is matching from original input Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am learning elasticsearch analyzer.I have a query regarding index time analysis and search time analysis.I understood the concept of this two types of analysis.

```
PUT test_index
{
"settings": {
  "number_of_replicas": 0,
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "custom_analyzer":{
        "type":"custom",
        "tokenizer":"standard",
        "filter":["lowercase","stemmer"]
      }
    }
  }
}, 
"mappings": { 
  "properties": {
    "text_field": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      
    }
  }
}
}
```

I add the documents in it

```
POST test_index/_doc/1
{
  "text_field":"The QUICK brown foxes jumped over the dog!"
}
```

In kibana discover I searched for **foxes jumped** it show me the matches
[image]

I am not using `search_analyzer` but still my query is acting like search time.When i query `foxes jumped` it should not match because in lucene we have `[the,quic,brown,fox,jump,over,the,lazy,dog]` but it is still matching.

i am following this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-index-search-time.html#analysis-same-index-search-analyzer) of elasticsearch

Comment: By default `search_analyzer` is the same as `analyzer` so stemming applied to the query as well

Comment: hey @ilvar , I also think so but in documentation they don't mention `search_analyzer`  value is also same as `analyzer` value. But I am not using search time analysis which is `search_analyzer`.

Comment: hey @ilvar thanks for this you were right.